# How to search for specific words in a raw_input?

Tags: python

This is the code I have been using and it just keeps coming up with errors, I'm using python 2.7 and advice or help would be really helpful. I'm trying

```
print "What is your mobile problem?"
print "----------------------------"


problem = raw_input
if "dropped" in problem
    print "sdghsd"

elif "broken" in problem
    print "sdfghf"
```

Comment: You're missing colons (`:`) after your `if` and `elif` conditions... This is a fundamental part of Python's syntax. Also, it's `raw_input()` in Python 2.7, not `raw_input`. Otherwise, your logic for searching string entries is sound.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2 the documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

if statement : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

```
print "What is your mobile problem?"
print "----------------------------"


problem = raw_input()
if "dropped" in problem:
    print "sdghsd"

elif "broken" in problem:
    print "sdfghf"
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is just fine the only thing that keep generating the error is that you forget to add **:** at the end of if statement

so your code should look like this

```
print "What is your mobile problem?"
print "----------------------------"

problem = raw_input()
if "dropped" in problem:
    print "sdghsd"

elif "broken" in problem:
    print "sdfghf"
```